# How to open drawer navigator not in a screen defined in drawernavigator

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

is it possible to open a drawer navigator from a screen that I DONT WANT IT TO BE INSIDE MY DRAWER NAVIGATOR

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:MainStackNavigator,//stack with tab
  },
  Pdf:{
    screen:AnotherScreen
  }
},
{
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  drawerWidth:Dimensions.get('window').width-50,

})
```

and this is my stacknavigator

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Main:{screen:AppDrawerNavigator,navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
  }},
  Login:{screen:LoginScreen},

  Map:{screen:MapScreen,navigationOptions:({navigation})=>({
    headerLeft:null,
    headerTransparent:true,
    headerRight:
        <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
           <IconMenu name='menu' size={25} style={{marginRight:20}} />
         </TouchableOpacity>})},
})
```

I want MapScreen to open the drawer i defined above (its not working , it says navigation is undefined.toggleDrawer() is not a function ,when i click on my IconMenu)

Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

Use this to open or close drawer

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

In your code you can use as

```
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

Comment: Thank you but  it says : undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.props.navigation'

Comment: in your code use as  navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());

Comment: i also added `import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';` but now when i click on my icon ,nothing happens

Comment: Are you using `navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());` this?

Comment: yes :
`        
<TouchableOpacity
         onPress={()=>navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}>
           <IconMenu name='menu' size={25} style={{marginRight:20}} />
         </TouchableOpacity>})}
`

Comment: follow this  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch NavigateAction with action to toggle drawer.

Try this:

```
  headerRight: () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: "Main",
      action: DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()
    });

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={()=> navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)}>
       <IconMenu name='menu' size={25} style={{marginRight:20}} />
     </TouchableOpacity>})},
    );
  }
```

And you should import NavigateActions and DrawerActions like that:

```
import { createAppContainer, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions } from "react-navigation-drawer";
```

action is executed in routeName which is DrawerNavigation in your case

[Here is the link to docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html)

[And here is a snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@kenodek/bd8657)

Comment: Thank you very much its almost works !!
the thing is that i want it inside my MAP screen and when i click on the icon , it opens the drawer as expected but take me back to my MAIN screen . 
i tried to change the `routeName ` to "Map" but again nothing happens.

Comment: I noticed the same behavior. I don't know why it happens yet